# python GUI to EXE with image and modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have created a Python GUI and trying to convert it to .exe with py2exe.
i am using following modules wx,matplotlib,numpy,time,serial,random and a .ico image as logo.

i tried create a setup.py file but it didn't work.need help creating setup file to generate .exe of my GUI.

Comment: would help if you pasted your setup.py and more information about how it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It would be convenient if you could provide some details regarding why the .EXE is not being created. If you can't provide the details then please go through these questions on Stackoverflow, they maybe helpful:

[How to build a python package into an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032813/how-to-build-a-python-package-into-an-exe)

[Making a standalone .exe file of a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634367/making-a-standalone-exe-file-of-a-python-script)

[Compiling python code into a single exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879465/compiling-python-code-into-a-single-exe)

[Convert Python Script to .exe that will work on all/most versions of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289979/convert-python-script-to-exe-that-will-work-on-all-most-versions-of-windows)

The best thing is to first refer to the [official documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)!