# Windows GUI app for python source?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, numpy

I have implemented a new algorithm in python, using sources which use the numpy, scipy libraries and deal with file I/O. I now need to build a Windows GUI app (python might not be installed in any form on a Windows OS) which will implement my existing python source, and take inputs such as file names and some other parameters. Please suggest some possible methods to make this happen.

Comment: You can include a python runtime local to your own app, then choose a python gui toolkit you like.

Comment: @Oerd Can you guide me through a way to locally include a python runtime?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking: Do you want to re-implement your algorithms in a more 'native' language? Or do you want to wrap your algorithms inside a 'windows' GUI? In the latter case: Since you need Python anyway to run your algorithm, you can just as well use a Python GUI (e.g. Tkinter, which is included in the python standard library).

Comment: I've never needed to do this myself, but there are many windows apps including py runtume (i.e. Sublime Text). Take a look at py2exe,  it will "bundle" your python code in a windows executable http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: @tobias_k I am interested in the second case of wrapping my algorithm, and as Oerd is suggesting I need to include a local python runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a GUI for your app, using different options like as below:

- [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/)
- [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)
- [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt)

  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520015/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-for-deploying-python-applications) may help you too.

Regarding creating the final executable you have some options like as below:

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [GUI2EXE](https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/)
- [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

There are other issues regarding the creation of an executable discussed here on the SO you may refer to them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170225/2382792) if you are interested.